# What does "T_RN" mean?

Tags: rebus

Take a look at these letters and tell me what it means.

> "T_RN"

It's a bit of a brainteaser. So think outside of the box to get the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It means

> No U-Turn - as in the road sign

Comment: Correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

"Torn without you". As though to expressing longing for a loved one.

OR similarly, and much more loosely "heart torn out"/"to have one's heart torn out".

Comment: Close. But not correct.

Comment: That would be "Turn without you", surely?

Comment: No. It's "No U Turn"

Comment: @AeJey Damn, of course it was :p

Comment: ;) An up vote for trying hard and getting close. :)

Comment: I just realised my answer makes no sense :D

Comment: Tornado (torn ate O) because the word TORN cannibalized the "O" from itself.